# Execute both custom function and commands function in a shared runtime using office js

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins

I have built an Excel Addin using Excel JS API.
The addin generates a custom function, so I have followed the instructions provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime)
so that I can create the required shared runtime environment. Now I would like to add a button on the Ribbon of xsi:type="ExecuteFunction"

I know that in general I have to specify the FunctionFile resource to point to commands.html and there (command.js)implement my function which will actually just open a link on a browser. It will be a help/manual button. But the configuration suggests that we should update FunctionFile resid to point to functions.html instead of commands.html. I have tried to make it this way but it does not work on Excel Desktop App. It only works on Excel Online.

Is there a workaround for this, so that I can keep my working custom function and trigger a function/command from a ribbon button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue:

1. I followed this [workaround](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime) to make sure that my custom function works in a shared runtime environment
2. I have updated manifest button's xsi type to xsi:type="ExecuteFunction"
3. I modified commands.js file and added my function there (the one referenced by the manifest in previous step)
4. In my taskpane.html file, I referenced the command.js file apart form functions.js

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="taskpane.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="commands.js"></script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

[Limitations of shared javascript runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYYPz.png)

Excel custom functions are currently not supported on iPad or in one-time purchase versions of Office 2019 or earlier.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. My custom function works. This is not a problem. The shared runtime has been configured successfully. The problem is that I can not open a browser window from a Ribbon button.

Comment: You mean office dialog? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins

Comment: No, office dialog works as expected as well.I think I have found the solution. I will post an answer in a little

Comment: @KonstantinosCheilakos Can you please suggest your solution over here ?